# Read Increment Then Write to a text file in perl

Tags: perl, file-io, increment

I have this little perl script which opens a txt file, reads the number in it, then overwrites the file with the number incremented by 1.  I can open and read from the file, I can write to the file but I"m having issues overwriting.  In addition, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without opening the file twice.  Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (FILE, "<", "data.txt") or die "$! error trying to a\
ppend";

 undef $/;

$number = <FILE>;
$number = int($number);
$myNumber = $number++;
print $myNumber+'\n';
close(FILE);

open(FILE, ">data.txt") or die "$! error";
print FILE $myNumber;
close(FILE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the line

```
$myNumber = $number++;
to 
$myNumber = $number+1;
```

That should solve the problem.

Below is how you could do by opening the file just once:

```
 open(FILE, "+<data.txt") or die "$! error";
 undef $/; 

 $number = <FILE>;
 $number = int($number);
 $myNumber = $number+1;
 seek(FILE, 0, 0); 
 truncate(FILE, tell FILE);
 print $myNumber+"\n";

 print FILE $myNumber;
 close(FILE);
```

Comment: Verber wanted to specifically open the file once and overwrite the number in there. Is there any other way to do it specifically for this  use case?

Comment: The seek is sufficient to overwrite the old number, as the new number will never be shorter than it. Well, with 'never' meaning, "if this is a problem, the solution is elsewhere."

Comment: Makes sense not sure what I was thinking :) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's good that you used the three-argument form of `open` the first time.  You also needed to do that in your second `open`.  Also, you should use lexical variables, i.e., those which begin with `my`, in your script--even for your file handles.

You can just increment the variable that holds the number, instead of passing it to a new variable.  Also, it's a good idea to use `chomp`.  This things being said, consider the following option:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

undef $/;

open my $fhIN, "<", "data.txt" or die "Error trying to open for reading: $!";
chomp( my $number = <$fhIN> );
close $fhIN;

$number++;

open my $fhOUT, ">", "data.txt" or die "Error trying to open for writing: $!";
print $fhOUT $number;
close $fhOUT;
```

Another option is to use the Module [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm), letting it handle all the I/O operations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw/edit_file/;

edit_file { chomp; $_++ } 'data.txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "data.txt";
my $number = 0;
my $fh;
if( -e $file ) {
    open $fh, "+<", $file or die "Opening '$file' failed, because $!\n";
    $number = <$fh>;
    seek( $fh, 0, 0 );
} else {                  # if no data.txt exists - yet
    open $fh, ">", $file or die "Creating '$file' failed, because $!\n";
}
$number++;
print "$number\n";
print $fh $number;
close( $fh );
```

If you're using a bash shell, and you save the code to test.pl, you can test it with:

```
for i in {1..10}; do ./test.pl; done
```

Then 'cat data.txt', should show a 10.